# Akka ask through a load balancer

Tags: scala, akka, load-balancing, marathon

I have the following setup:
`[app-a Containers] <-[load balancer]-> [app-b Containers]`

The containers are Docker containers and a set of containers are assigned a DNS name like `app-a.marathon.mesos` and `app-b.marathon.mesos`.

Now when an actor in `app-a` makes an ask to a remote actor on `app-b`, the `app-b`'s sender becomes `app-a.marathon.mesos`.

This is tremendously problemmatic because now, the reply to the asking actor may or may not arrive – it may arrive at any of the `app-a` containers.

What is the best way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Your setup seems to make it actually impossible to implement your goal because a basic constraint, the fact that the actor path is unique is violated. 
I think there are 2 options:

1. Update your load balancer to support some kind of specific addressing
2. Encode the follow-up operations you want to execute on app-a upon receiving the answer into the message itself, allowing the app-b to actually execute them (or the random receiver in app-a).